# Stretch CSS background (change width only)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image (intended as a background) which I wish to place on the bottom of a container.

I want this image to maintain its current height, but be stretched to the width of the container.

Here is what I have already:

```
background:url('images/poll-graph.svg') no-repeat center bottom;
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<section id="sec-feature-polling">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>This is a heading</h2>
        <p class="subheading">This is a subheading</p>

    </div>
</section>
```

I tried adding `background-size: 100%` but this causes the image to scale proportionally (height increases).

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0.

Any assistance would be gratefully received :-)

Comment: Try using max-width instead of background-size.
 max-width: 100%;

Comment: `background-size: 100% $Npx;` where `$N` is the pixel height of the image

Comment: @chiliNUT  How do we make text bold (or mark it as code) in comment section?

Comment: lol @NoobieSatan use backticks for code, double asterisks for bold... ` `code` ` `**` **bold** `**` and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It would have been much of a help if you would have shared your HTML structure but still.

Put a `div` container with a `class`. I will take class to be xyz.

now in your CSS do something like this...

```
.xyz {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will change the height of the xyz container based on the content inside it.

For some reason, I am not sure if we could use all this one line

```
background:url('images/poll-graph.svg') no-repeat center bottom;
```

**[Update]** Based on the HTML structure you have added, and I understand that you wish to place image at the bottom of the container.

Try this:

1. Close all your container div classes (since you are using bootstrap and container class adds padding)
2. Now since you want it to be below the container, create a new div class below the container
3. Inside that div class add the content you want over that background

Then try something like this as your css on the class of newly div you have created

```
background-image: url('../images/college-cover.jpeg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 750px;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @NoobieSatan. Unfortunately, this just shifted the background to the left of the container (it didn't cause it to span the full width). I have added the HTML structure to the question as per your request.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If yes, Which version?

Comment: I am indeed, version 4.0.0 :-)

Comment: On which class are you adding 
    `background:url('images/poll-graph.svg')` ?

Comment: It's being added to `#sec-feature-polling`

Comment: Updated my answer